# LSF - Mount a cgroups.cpuset for jobs

Tags: linux, centos6, lsf, cgroups

Is there a way to use cgroups.cpuset with lsf? It looks like we can only use the freezer and acct from cgroups with the v9.1 of LFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for cpuset was released in LSF 9.1.1.1 (GA July 31, 2013).  The feature adds a new parameter to lsf.conf `LSB_RESOURCE_ENFORCE`. You can set it to `cpu`, `memory` or both.  You need to enable the [cpu and memory affinity feature](http://www.ccs.miami.edu/hpc/lsf/9.1.1/lsf_admin/index.htm?numa_cpu_mem_affinity_support_lsf.html~main) of LSF to use cpuset.

Comment: thanks @MichaelClosson! I modified the lsf.conf file to include: LSB_RESOURCE_ENFORCE="cpu", LSF_PROCESS_TRACKING=Y,  LSF_LINUX_CGROUP_ACCT=Y Then, lsb.hosts for setting the affinity for hosts and restart LSF. However, when we run the command: bsub -n 4 -R "affinity[core:distribute=pack(socket=1)]" ./myapp, myapp can still use not allowed cores. Is there anything else that I should set in LSF?

Comment: @ChristianePousa Did you enable schmod_affinity in lsb.modules? Can you see the host topology in bhosts -l -aff?  Can you see the job affinity allocation in bjobs -l -aff?  Good Luck!

Comment: After some search I found out that cpuset only works in LSF when affinity is used. Now, everything is working.... Thank you.